# ChartJS multiple sub labels for label

Tags: chart.js

I want to have multiple sub labels for one label in chart.js, is this possible?

[image]

Comment: There may be a way to produce such sub labels. Please show us the code of what your already have, possible together with the data used for creating  above chart.

Comment: This is what I have: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WpMdw7HJbb/

Comment: JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ehtxap51/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define an additional `yAxis` that contains nothing but the `labels` for the stacked bars.
The we will add `yAxisID` property to each dataset. This must match the scale properties `scales.yAxes.id` of the standard `category` axis.

```
yAxes: [{
      labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']
    },
    {
      id: 'yAxis1',
      type: 'category',
      offset: true,
      gridLines: {
        offsetGridLines: true
      }
    }
  ]
```

Please have a look at the runnable code below.

```js
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Dataset 1",
      yAxisID: 'yAxis1',
      backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
      categoryPercentage: 1,
      barPercentage: 0.8,
      stack: "Stack 0",
      data: [1, 2, 3],
    },
    {
      label: "Dataset 2",
      yAxisID: 'yAxis1',
      backgroundColor: "#0000FF",
      categoryPercentage: 1,
      barPercentage: 0.8,
      stack: "Stack 0",
      data: [5, 4, 3],
    },
    {
      label: "Dataset 3",
      yAxisID: 'yAxis1',
      backgroundColor: "#00CC00",
      categoryPercentage: 1,
      barPercentage: 0.8,
      stack: "Stack 1",
      data: [6, 5, 4],
    },
    {
      label: "Dataset 4",
      yAxisID: 'yAxis1',
      backgroundColor: "#000000",
      categoryPercentage: 1,
      barPercentage: 0.8,
      stack: "Stack 2",
      data: [6, 5, 4],
    }
  ]
};

new Chart('chart', {
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: barChartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']
        },
        {
          id: 'yAxis1',
          type: 'category',
          offset: true,
          gridLines: {
            offsetGridLines: true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked",
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: "index",
      intersect: false,
    },
    responsive: true,
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: How is this possible for a 2D array? If I have [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], how can I place 123 for A and 456 for B? And labels: ["A" ... ] does not work in typescript?

Comment: @newbie: I don't exactly understand this new issue. Please post a new question and explain in detail what you're looking for.

Comment: I have an 2D array with the following data [ [1,2,3 ], [4,5,6] ], and for each index I want to create a new group. So: 1 and 4, subgroup A. 2 and 5 subroup B. And 3 and 6 subroup C. 

And yAxes:Labels does not work in typescript. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post this comment as a new question instead.