# Chart.js sublabels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to do something like:
[ChartJS multiple sub labels for label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343438/chartjs-multiple-sub-labels-for-label)

This old question uses v2, which I am using v4 now and I also want to have some groups with more subitems than others. Here is rough code that is close to what I want:

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new Chart('myChart', {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Min',
                    data: [7.16, 1, 2.8, 1, 16]
                },
                {
                    label: 'Max',
                    data: [85.86, 29.55, 181.78, 70.54, 89]
                },
                {
                    label: 'Average',
                    data: [29.03, 13.17, 39.13, 40.61, 51.50]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            indexAxis: 'y',
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom'
                }
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    reverse: true
                },
                customGroups: {
                    labels: ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3'],
                    axis: 'y',
                    reverse: true,
                    ticks: {
                        maxRotation: 90,
                        minRotation: 90,
                        major: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        align: 'end'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

What I am looking for is Group 1 to be around label A, Group 2 to be around label B, C, D and Group 3 to be around label E. The Group should be centered across those rows.

I am open to another library, but this one seems like the nicest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `ticks.align` has no effect when `ticks` are rotated. You could use `ticks.labelOffset` instead. For further information, consult [Common tick options to all cartesian axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/_common_ticks.html#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes) from the Chart.js documentation.

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code below and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Min',
        data: [7.16, 1, 2.8, 1, 16]
      },
      {
        label: 'Max',
        data: [85.86, 29.55, 181.78, 70.54, 89]
      },
      {
        label: 'Average',
        data: [29.03, 13.17, 39.13, 40.61, 51.50]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        reverse: true
      },      
      customGroups: {        
        axis: 'y',
        labels: ['Group 1', '', 'Group 2', '', 'Group 3'],
        reverse: true,
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          lineWidth: [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
        },
        ticks: {                  
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 90,
          labelOffset: -22
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```